What measurement can demonstrate whether someone has decompression illness?
My understanding is that DCI occurs due to nitrogen bubbles forming in the blood when a diver ascends from higher to lower pressures. DCI typically occurs once these bubbles are large and/or numerous enough.
Dive computers typically run one of these algorithms to estimate how your tissues will uptake and release nitrogen whilst diving to ensure that you probably don't get DCI.
I'm wondering if there's any physical measurement that can be performed which would directly assess the bubble load of your tissues?

Physical measurements during an ascent or experimental? I'm unsure of what good it would do, as it would seem physical measurements would be impeded by a diver's gear, but I don't dive, so...

@anongoodnurse - Well, I was hoping that there would be a test that's generally carried out in a hospital that might be possible to carry out during ascent as well given equipment designed for it

Apparently, bubbles in the heart can be seen on an ultrasound: https://dan.org/research-reports/research-studies/exploring-decompression-bubbles-using-advanced-ultrasound-techniques/. However, this only correlates with DCI, and can't diagnose it. In the field, DCI is diagnosed using signs and symptoms such as joint pain. (I am not a medical professional)

Researchers have been exploring various imaging techniques and monitoring methods to detect or quantify gas bubbles in tissues: Ultrasound Imaging, to detect and monitor gas bubbles in divers tissues post-dive to check for larger gas emboli within blood vessels or organs. MRI for detecting microbubbles or regional differences in tissue perfusion due to gas emboli formation. Transcranial Doppler Ultrasonography to assess changes in cerebral blood flow velocity as an indirect measure of potential arterial gas embolism affecting brain circulation. Transthoracic echocardiography to evaluate venous gas embolism by visualizing bubbles passing through the heart chambers. Gas Detection Devices (portable breath analyzers) to measure nitrogen levels exhaled by divers which could provide some indication indirectly about their body's saturation level. Electrical Impedance Tomography to detect bubbles in the lungs.
